# Centos 8 install blocks admin login

Tags: admin

I have been porting my Magento 2.3.7 store over to Centos 8 from Centos 7. Install works okay except for blocking admin logins.

If I update the admin user password using the `bin/magento` command-line tool, then I can log in again. It would appear that the encryption of the passwords is different between Centos 7 and version 8.

What is different between Centos 7 to Centos 8 that breaks the encryption of the admin passwords?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for answering my own question, but I thought it might help somebody down the line who comes across the same problem.

My database under Centos 7 used the Argon 2ID13 hashing algorithm to hash my admin passwords and probably the user passwords as well. When I installed my system on Centos 8 the Sodium extension was not installed that implements the Argon 2ID13 hashing algorithm. Consequently, when trying to log into the system on Centos 8, Magento didn't have access to the correct hashing algorithm to decode the salt from the database. When I updated the admin password, Magento dropped down to using the SHA256 algorithm.

The fix was very simple, I just needed to install the `PHP-sodium` PHP module which implements the Argo 1ID13 algorithm.